# Angular TinyMCE add custom plugin

Tags: angular, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I have an `Angular` application and I am using `TinyMCE` as my editor.
Is there any way I can add a custom plugin for the editor with angular? I haven't found any example online with angular.

What I am trying to achieve is to add a button to the toolbar which opens a custom-built angular component.
I have added a simple TinyMCE editor example on stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k3nguv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define setup method in your component and refer to that method in editor configuration:

**ts**

```
setup(editor) {
  editor.ui.registry.addButton('myCustomToolbarButton', {
    text: 'My Custom Button',
    onAction: function () {
      alert('Button clicked!');
    }
  });
}
```

**html**

```
<editor
  [init]="{
    height: 500,
    menubar: false,
    plugins: ['paste'],
    toolbar: 'bold italic underline myCustomToolbarButton',
    setup: setup
  }"
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hwlmtp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**